# $f\in K[t]$ is irreducible if and only if $G$ $(\Gamma(L:K))$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$.

Tags: galois-theory, galois-representations, galois-connections

Let $K$ be a field, $f\in K[t]$ separable over $K$, $L$ the splitting field of $f$ over $K$, and $G=\Gamma(L:K)$.
I need to prove that $f$ is irreducible if and only if $G$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$.

I was able to show one direction, that $f$ irreducible implies $G$ acts transitively on the roots. I'm stuck on the other direction of implication; supposing $G$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$. Any guidance or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: See [my answer there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561512/f-is-irreducible-iff-g-act-transitively-on-the-roots/1561699#1561699).

Comment: If there is $\sigma \in Gal(L/K)$  such that $\sigma(\alpha) = \beta$ then $\sigma_{| K(\alpha)}$ is an isomorphism $K(\alpha) \to K(\beta)$